# python 'TypeError: argument must be string or read-only character buffer, not tuple'

Tags: python, string

I wrote this code using python 2.7:

```
class LoadBalancerHandler:

    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.server_socket = socket.socket(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        file = open(file_name)
        setup_apps(file.read())

    def listen(self, host='localhost', port=80):
        self.server_socket.bind((host,port))
        self.server_socket.listen(5)
        while True:
            (client_socket, address) = self.server_socket.accept()
            threadHandling = ThreadHandling(client_socket, self)
            threadHandling.start()
```

but I get this error:

> TypeError: argument must be string or read-only character buffer, not tuple

This error is raised by the line:`self.server_socket.bind((host,port))`

Comment: Your options to socket.socket(...) seem suspicious.  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html.  You may have meant socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)???

Comment: What parameters did you use to call `listen`? Add `print(repr(host), repr(port))` to see what you got.

Comment: For instance, suppose you called `someobject.listen(('localhost', 80))` that is, you passed a tuple as `host`, you may get an error like this.

Comment: i printed them!
host is string 'localhost' and port is int 1234

Comment: i changed the the options as you said but got an error:
"Protocol not supported"

Answer (score 2):

Again, i think your options to socket.socket(...) are incorrect.  If you're trying to create a TCP listener, this works

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('localhost',5555))
s.listen(5)
```

Comment: please note that for low port ranges (<1024?) you may get a permission denied as these are protected ports.